# Is there any solution to make this line more tight or make this layout nicer?

Tags: equations

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % 
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}  % Use Input in the format of Algorithm  
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} % Use Output in the format of Algorithm  
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{}
\label{alg:algorithm1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \State Required system configuration ($RSC$) = Find\_required\_configuration($BoPs$, $BoRs$)


\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that you must only use one `\documentclass{...}`

Answer (score 1):

The spaces become so large because latex can't hyphenate the long variable name from your next line. You could help latex find possible hyphenation points, but the result might be confusing.

To avoid overly large space between the works, you could instead set the text in `\raggedright`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % 
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}  % Use Input in the format of Algorithm  
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} % Use Output in the format of Algorithm  
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{}
\label{alg:algorithm1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \raggedright
    \State Required system configuration ($RSC$) = Find\_required\_configuration($BoPs$, $BoRs$)


\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]